# How to add space between 2 bar plot python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I tried to add space between 2 bars
plot.bar([value for value in range(len(y))+0.25], z, width=0.4) 
but it was showing error "cant convert list to float"

```
x = x[xleftpos:xrightpos]
y = y[xleftpos:xrightpos]
z = z[xleftpos:xrightpos]


plot.bar([value for value in range(len(x))],y,width=0.4,)

plot.bar([value for value in range(len(x))], z, width=0.4)
plot.set_xticks([idx + 0.5 for idx in range(len(x))])
plot.set_xticklabels(x, rotation=35, ha='right', size=10)
xlocs = [idx + 0.5 for idx in range(len(x))]
for i, v in enumerate(y):
    plt.text(xlocs[i] - 0.99, v - 0.98, str(v))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this code worked for me                                                                                  
       plot.bar([value for value in range(len(x))],y,width=-0.3 , align='edge')

        plot.bar([value for value in range(len(x))], z, width=0.3, align='edge')

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to separate the bars horizontally or vertically? For vertical separation, use `bottom:

```
plt.bar(range(5), range(5))
plt.bar(range(5), range(-5,0), bottom=-0.25)
```

Output:

[image]

Also, as you can notice, you can do `plt.bar(range(len(x)), y)` without list comprehension.

For horizontal shift:

```
plt.bar([x+.25 for x in range(5)], range(5))
plt.bar(range(5), range(-5,0), bottom=-0.25)
```

You can also use `np.arange(5) + 0.25`:

```
plt.bar(np.arange(5) + 0.25, range(5))
plt.bar(range(5), range(-5,0), bottom=-0.25)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: need a horizontal gap and removing list makes my code different